# Find all incomplete songs in iTunes library

Tags: itunes

Some of the tracks in my iTunes library which I have downloaded from the iTunes Store are incomplete.  I understand the recommended solution to this problem to delete and re-download the track.

This advice is only useful if I know which tracks are incomplete, and I often don't find out until I try to play them.  Is there a way to detect *which* tracks are incomplete in one's library?

Why doesn't iTunes use checksums to make sure the tracks are complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect incompleteness iTunes would need something to compare the track to. Unfortunately this is not available therefore you really are out of luck here and have to download each song individually once you find it by listening.